# cannot get local IP address with rtcpeerconnection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, firefox, webrtc

I tried to get local IP address of a client,and I use RTCPeerConnection,but it doesnt work in chrome & Firefox,here is the source code,what am I supposed to do to make it work in chrome & Firefox [Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvbBB.png) [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FHlO.png) [another browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rap9z.png),thank you very much!

Comment: Hope this helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837471/how-to-get-local-internal-ip-with-javascript

Comment: @HimanshuPandey unfortunately,this doesnt work in chrome & firefox