# Is it possible to get a user's IP address by decoding the mDNS string received with the help of webRTC?

Tags: javascript, ip, webrtc

I've spent some time looking at different answers, and the best I've found was [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58433913/2891356) from a different SO question.

The issue is that this returns an mDNS string, like so:

```
abcd1234-1e1e-1e1e-1e1e-abcd1a2bc3de.local
```

I have a legitimate use case for this feature, and I've tried finding answers or libraries that are capable of decoding this string, such as [webrtc-ips](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-ips), but this package returns an empty array for me.

Has anyone been able to figure out a way to do this without a third-party, like [api.ipify](https://api.ipify.org) or similar services?

Comment: Do you need to do the decoding in the browser? You can get the IPs outside of it easily `dns-sd -q abcd1234-1e1e-1e1e-1e1e-abcd1a2bc3de.local`. But inside the browser it is by design. I wouldn't build anything that uses a workaround, will probably break in the future!

Answer (score 2):

The design purpose of these mdns strings is that you can not decode them outside the local network.

If you have a legitimate use-case you can explain it in https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-extensions/issues/87 which discusses asking for permission to expose IP addresses without the current workaround to ask for camera permissions.